# Countif with one Criteria, but only count Cost Center once

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I have the following problem:

I have a list with 2 columns, in the first columns there are several cost centers and in the second are Values. I am looking formula, that counts every Cost Center if the value is not 0, but only once. So every cost center is counted once, if the value is not 0. I used different combinations of countif, but I do not get a correct solution, as shown in this picture:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please share the formula you are currently working with. This is not a script/formula writing service, but we will help you with what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:
=SUM(IF($B$2:$B$14,1/(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$14,"<>"& 0, $A$2:$A$14, $A$2:$A$14)), 0))

Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>
B2:B14 is the Column Value
A2:A14 is Cost Center Column
1/(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$14,"<>"& 0, $A$2:$A$14, $A$2:$A$14)) will result:
1/{3; 3; 3; 3; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1}
it result { 0.333333333333333; 0.333333333333333; 0.333333333333333; 0.333333333333333;1;1;1;1; #DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;1;1}

IF($B$2:$B$14) will evaluate to True if B2:B14<>0 and to False if B2:B14=0
Which means when True it will calculate 1/countifs() to count distinct values
and 0 when False
And I repeat it is an array formula not a simple formula

Comment: @ yass, if this is not the place for this comment, please let me know.  I understood this function (working from inside out) until I got to the IF(). It looks like the logical test is the range $B$2:$B$14, the value if true is 1/COUNTIFS(...) and the value if false is 0.  Could you explain how the range can evaluate to TRUE or FALSE?  Thanks.

Comment: If you  are the one who down voted the answer, kindly try it and find out the result before voting I tried to explain about the If in the answer

Comment: No I didn't vote it down, I thought it was the best answer.  And I DID try it - works great ! Just haven't figured out the IF() and thought it would be faster (and easier) to ask you.  :-). Thanks for the extra info.

Comment: A simple IF() using just the range followed by 1,0) gives a #value! error unless it's entered as an array formula.  Next I'll try to figure out why.  And I still think yours is the best answer, so I'll vote you back up to 0.  Not a BIG complement. I guess, buy hey.

Comment: You are write you can't just use if without count or sum with the same way that is why Sum(if(B2:B14,1,0)) array formula and thank you for voting

Comment: So would enclosing it in SUMPRODUCT() work here to eliminate the need for an array formula?  I think I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Sumproduct() works differently you cannot use if inside it maybe without duplicate it works

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a helper column to show only cost centres with non-zero values by putting `=IF(B2=0,"",A2)` in C2.

Then count the unique texts in the helper column while ignoring blanks using `=SUMPRODUCT((helper<>"")*(1/COUNTIF(helper,helper&"")))` in C12

[image]